# How do I fix a NullException when trying to inject a DataSource bean via a Service class?

Tags: xml, web-services, spring, jdbc, dependency-injection

So, I have a simple REST web application and if my Controller calls the DAO directly, the JDBC calls work just fine, but if my controller calls another class that calls the DAO on my behalf, it fails with NullPointerException (NPE).

Here's my Controller:

```java
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Path("/emsrequest")
public class EMSRequest {

    // I'm using this for testing
    @GET
    @Path("/xml/{accountNumber}")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String requestByAccountNumber_XML(
            @PathParam("accountNumber") String accountNumber) {

        ReqSubTest los = new ReqSubTest();

        return "account (LOS) number is : " + los.testSql(Integer.parseInt(accountNumber)) + "!";
    }
}
```

Here's the intermediate (service) class:

```java
package com.company.demo.mercury.processmanager.components;

import com.company.demo.pmrws.dao.EMSRequestDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ReqSubTest {

    @Autowired
    EMSRequestDaoImpl dao = new EMSRequestDaoImpl();

    public int testSql(int quantity){
        return dao.getNextTableIds("sys_process_tbl", quantity);

    }
}
```

And here's the DAO Implementation:

```java
package com.company.demo.pmrws.dao;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

public class EMSRequestDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EMSRequestDaoImpl.class);

    public int getNextTableIds(String tableName, int quantity) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Entering getNextTableIds");
        }

        if (getJdbcTemplate() == null) {
            System.out.println("UH OH!");
        }

        String selectSql = "select next_id "
                + "from sys_key_tbl "
                + "where table_name = ? ";
        String updateSql = "update sys_key_tbl "
                + "set next_id = ? "
                + "where table_name = ? and next_id = ? ";
        int lastId = -1;
        int updateCount = 0;
        while (updateCount == 0) {
            lastId = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(selectSql,
                    new Object[]{tableName});
            updateCount = getJdbcTemplate().update(updateSql,
                    new Object[]{lastId + quantity, tableName, lastId});
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Leaving getNextTableIds");
        }
        return lastId + 1;
    }
}
```

The Application Context XML:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.demo.pmrws"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDataSource" />
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:blah:10240/BLAH_DB1" />
        <property name="username" value="blah" />
        <property name="password" value="blah" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceMain" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDataSource" />
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:blah:10240/BLAH_DB2" />
        <property name="username" value="blah" />
        <property name="password" value="blah" />
    </bean>
    </bean>

    <!--    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="emsResponseDao" class="com.company.demo.pmrws.dao.EMSResponseDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="emsStatusDao" class="com.company.demo.pmrws.dao.EMSStatusDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMain" />
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="collateralSybaseEmsDao" class="com.company.demo.dao.CollateralSybaseEmsDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="collateralSybaseDao" class="com.company.demo.dao.CollateralSybaseDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="emsRequestDao" class="com.company.demo.pmrws.dao.EMSRequestDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.demo.mercury.processmanager.components" />

</beans>
```

What am I missing?  BTW, this is Spring 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `ReqSubTest los = new ReqSubTest();` create a new normal java Object instance but not a Spring Bean, therefore there get nothing injected into the `los` instance.

Three ways to fix it.

- instead of `ReqSubTest los = new ReqSubTest();` inject `los` via Spring, but this requires that `EMSRequest` is a Spring bean too

Example:

```
@Component public class EMSRequest {

    @Autowire ReqSubTest los;

    public String requestByAccountNumber_XML(@PathParam("accountNumber") String accountNumber) {
        return "account (LOS) number is : " + los.testSql(Integer.parseInt(accountNumber)) + "!";
    } 
}
```

- instead of `ReqSubTest los = new ReqSubTest();` use `ReqSubTest los = springApplicationContext.getBean(ReqSubTest.class)`
- If you use real AspectJ then you can add `@Configurable` and then Spring inject other beans even if an instance is created via `new` (Requires to be enabled via `<context:spring-configured />`) - You can add the annotation to `EMSRequest` and then use normal injection like suggeted in the first item, or add it to `ReqSubTest`

Comment: Can you elaborate on bullet point #1?  An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I added an example. But if this works or not depends on whether `EMSRequest` itself is a Spring Bean or not. BTW: if it is not a Spring bean, then you can use the technique from bullet point #3 to inject the dependencies (add `@Configurable` to `EMSRequest`)

Comment: It's not a bean, so I decided to make it one.  Gives me the following error:  
       Error creating bean with name 'emsRequest' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
        Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
         Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.company.demo.mercury.processmanager.components.ReqSubTest]: 
          No property 'dataSource' found. Please see server.log for more details.  But it's CLEARLY there.

Comment: this is the bean:     <bean id="emsRequest" class="com.sungard.sims.mercury.processmanager.components.ReqSubTest">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMain" />
    </bean>

Comment: Also, when I tried `@Autowire ReqSubTest los`, the IDE complained of an annotation error but `@Autowired ReqSubTest los`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: It turns out that this was a bit helpful but your first bullet point had me re-check my code (actually, legacy code) and found out that that deep within the bowels of the code, new classes were being instantiated, thus, essentially breaking and nullifying the dao.  Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the problem. The problem is in your service class `ReqSubTest`.

You have autowired the DAO class there but you should not initialize it there. So just remove the initialization part of your DAO declaration and you are good to go. So now your declaration in service class will look like below.

```
@Autowired
private EMSRequestDaoImpl dao;
```

And in your controller also you need to autowire the Service class. And don't create its new object in function itself.

```
@Autowired
private ReqSubTest service;
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Would the class need to be @Component?

Comment: I've tried this method and get the following: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emsRequest' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.sungard.sims.mercury.processmanager.components.ReqSubTest]: No property 'dataSource' found

Comment: The bean I added:     <bean id="emsRequest" class="com.company.demo.mercury.processmanager.components.ReqSubTest">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

Comment: Of course you need to have `@Component` annotation on the class that you are going to autowire in any other class. Or you can also put proper annotation like `@Controller`, `@Service` or `@Repository` as per the functionality that class is serving.